# Entity Framework 6 reuse connections multiple databases

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework in order to connect to a number of databases stored on a number of server. 
For example server 1 has 100 databases and server 2 has 100 databases. All databases have the exact same database structure.

In entity framework I set the connection string manually appending the name of the database. To do this I have created a partial class with the same name as the MyEntities.edmx file.

```
public partial class MyEntities {
    public MyEntities(string connectionString, string databaseName) : base(connectionString) {
        this.Database.Connection.ChangeDatabase(databaseName);
    }

    public static MyDbEntities CreateFromDatabaseName(string databaseName) {
        String connectionString = "metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=\"server=mysql.mydomain.tld;User Id=user;password=pass;Persist Security Info=True\""
        return new MyEntities(connectionString, databaseName);
    }
}
```

Function-wise it works great. I can just call MyEntities.CreateFromDatabaseName("dbname") to create a entity framework instance connected to the specific database. The problem is that every time I do this it connects 2-3 actual mysql connections for each app server node. I would instead like it to re-use connections on the same data base server even though they are bound to a different database on that server and thus reducing the number of connections.
Is this possible with EF 6.x?

Comment: Usually you should not let the context live longer than the (web) request. It consumes a lot of resources and hinders application threading.

Comment: @WicherVisser sound advice, but there's no indication here that this is a web app.

Comment: This is not a web app, and there are a lot of long running queries

Comment: For standalone applications, contexts are advised to bound to the life-cycle of a form or view, or the equivalent thereof.

Comment: are you using connection pooling? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: Yes @WicherVisser Connection Pooling is enabled. My problem is that the pooling seem per database, while I would like it to be per database server. I would rather like the connection to switch to another database than to spawn a completely new connection.

Comment: What you want is to use an existing context and change its connection string? Bad idea, but possible it seems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261648/entity-framework-changing-database-of-existing-dbcontext. No idea about performance impact.

Comment: @WicherVisser No, as you can see in my code above I never want to change the connection string, only the database.

Comment: I expect that changing the database in the connection string is effectively changing the connection string itself.

Comment: @WicherVisser this.Database.Connection refers to the connection itself and not to the connection string.